# Can I use a different power adapter with my TV with different Ampere output

Tags: android-tv, smart-tv

I am not sure if this is the right place to ask this, but here it goes.
I have a sony W80C android TV which is not powering on.
I tried following steps to find out the problem:
1. Tried another remote (mobile phone IR blaster)
2. Currently trying a different power adapter.
Here's the problem,
The original power adapter outputs 19.5V 5.2A and the new one I ordered is 19.5V 4.35A. So the TV is not powering on.
I thought it's because of the difference between ampere that's why it's not working.
But the person who sold me this is saying that this power adapter works with all Sony TV and he even tested it on 43" Android TV and it works and said there was an issue with my TV.

I just want to know if it's possible to power up the TV with lower Ampere output or not. If that's the case then I will send my TV to repair.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that both of the chargers are DC, I hope the new charger isn't AC.

The original charger was 19.5V 5.2A = 101.4 Watts
The new charger is 19.5V 4.35A = 84.825 Watts

My guess is that the power isn't enough to power up your TV, and if by chance your TV works with 84.825 Watts then the new charger will be very hot and will burn soon because the TV needs more power and the source isn't able to provide it.

## In general consider this when buying any replacement charger:

- Don't buy unknown/cheap chargers
- Type of current flow should be the same as the original charger: **DC = DC** or **AC = AC**
- Voltage should be exactly the same : **19.5 = 19.5**
- Amperage provided by the source (New Charger) **should be More or Equal** to the Amperage needed by the destination (Ex: TV)

So; in your case; the new charger should be :

**19.5V DC Exactly**  and **4.35A or more**

Comment: The default charger provided with TV has 5.2A output but the new one has the same voltage with 4.35 A . So it is not impossible for the TV to power on with less Ampere ?

Comment: if by chance the TV will power up, you'll end up with a burned charger because it can't provide enough power.